# Spring URI - Controller Mapping

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have a controller mapping that worked before I put in Spring Security. I am learning MVC and Spring.

Now I get a PageNotFoundException saying that path cannot be found. If you see my controller it maps to /user and the method to get the data in /list.

I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be useful.

Here is the information:

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<!-- Bean to show you Di in GAE, via Spring, also init the UserController -->
<!--  <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
 -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.principalmvl.lojackmykids">
 <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(service|constroller)\..*"/>
 </context:component-scan>
    <!-- Enables JSR-303 -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />


<bean class="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory"
    factory-method="getUserService" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>datastoreFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datastoreFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**UserController.java**

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/user")
 public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddUserPage(ModelMap model) {

    return "add";

}


// get all users

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public  List<Contact> listCustomer( ModelMap model) {

    List<Contact> users = Datastore.query(Contact.class).asList();

    model.addAttribute("userList", users);

    return users;

 }
}
```

**LoginController.Java [This is the first controller that gets called]**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LookupUserServlet.class
    .getName());

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String landing() {
    return "landing";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/home.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {

    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/disabled.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String disabled() {
    return "disabled";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/logout.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    request.getSession().invalidate();

    String logoutUrl = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().createLogoutURL(
            "/loggedout.jsp");

    response.sendRedirect(logoutUrl);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedout.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loggedOut() {
    return "loggedout";
}


@RequestMapping("/ListUsers")
public String ListUser() {

    return "users/ListUsers";

}

@RequestMapping("/SendAll")
public String SendAll() {

    return "sendmessage/SendAll";

}
```

In my ListUsers method should I redirect to the controller called UserController?

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to hit exactly that is returning 404?

Comment: I'm trying to go to /user/list. This should be mapped in the controller to the class and the method but Spring says page not found. I'm wondering if it has some configuration related to JSPs and it gets confused.

Comment: So that is a /user/list POST which means you are getting 404 when attempting to submit a form. I am going to make an assumption and post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your list has extra /

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Change it to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

This is on assumption that your form being submitted is pointing to "/list"

Comment: Aeseir..thanks for responding. It isn't that. I have it as this @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET). Here is something interesting. I added this to the web.xml  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name
  <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>  and it produces this in the logs. /user/list/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/

Answer (score 0):

So I moved the URI mapping to my controller called LoginController and the request worked. My question is now, why is my UserController not getting picked up. I have the context base-scan scanning in all the base packages and my controller.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Upon more investigation. I believe that Eclipse did something to the Java class. When I looked at the Java class and how Eclipse annotates it, it did not have a corresponding "twisty" that shows a contractor of the class.

I created another Java class and added the code and it worked appropriately.